# Return All Meteor Users Except The Current User?

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a page that displays all the registered users, but wanted to omit the current user. Is there a way to return all Meteor's users *except* the current user.

Here is my html:

```
<template name="users">
    <div class="contentDiv">
        <div class="blueTop pageContent" id="profileName">Users</div>
            {{#each users}}
                <div class="pageContent text">
                    <a class="user link"  id="{{_id}}">{{profile.firstName}} {{profile.lastName}}</a>
                    <button class="addFriend">Add Friend</button>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>    
</template>
```

And my javascript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("users");

    Template.users.helpers({
        users:function(){
            return Meteor.users.find({}, {sort: {firstName: -1}}).fetch();       
        }
    });
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("users",function(){
        return Meteor.users.find();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the comparison query operator **[`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)** to filter out documents which are not equal to a specified value, in your case `Meteor.userId()`.

For example:

```
Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}});
```

Comment: Thanks! @Matthias Eckhart

Comment: I've tried to do exactly that but the current user persists and comes back as well..

Comment: @webkit Please open a new question and include your code. I'll be more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a publication, you can simply use the [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator. `this.userId` is set on all publication functions as the current user.

```
Meteor.publish('all_users', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({
    _id: { $ne: this.userId }
  });
});
```